# DAX Getting a measure to ignore a slicer and concatenates values in a column that contain a specific string

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a table as follows:

| name | state |
| --- | --- |
| bob | joyful |
| bob | joyous |
| bob | sad |
| susan | joyful |

I set up a slicer for the names. I need a measure, which will display in a card, a concatenated list of all states that contain the test "joy" AND that match the filtered name from the slicer.

For example, if I select bob, the output should be:
joyful, joyous

If I select susan, the output should be
joyful

I have the following measure, which only concatenates all values that match the filtered name:

```
measure = CONCATENATEX(VALUES('test'[state]),'test'[state], ", ")
```

1. How do I get it to only concatenate the values that contain "joy"?
2. if I add another slicer for the state and select joyful, the output is only the word joyful. How do I get my measure to ignore the selected values in the state slicer and only look at the selected values from the name slicer?

Comment: `Measure:=CONCATENATEX(FILTER(Table1,SEARCH("joy",Table1[state],,0)>0),Table1[state],", ")`

Comment: As to ignoring a slicer, I don't believe that's possible. Indeed, why would it be? Why have a slicer if it is to be ignored?